# How to log in to a form (POST) and download the web pages' source? (Java, android)

Tags: java, android, forms, post

I need an app, that you would give your login credentials, and it would log in for you, download the data and display it (into a `TextView` for example). I can pull the data out of the source and all that, but i don't know how to do the logging in and stuff. (Well I know I should send the credentials via post request, but that's about all.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using JSOUP to connect and login using credentials. It gives you the ability to do POST and GET requests. Once logged in you can navigate to pages by providing links and cookies. **The challenge will be to make sure to provide all the data necessary to successfully login**.

For example:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://some-site.com/login.jsp")
                        .data("username", "somename")
                        .data("password", "apass")
                        .method(Method.POST)
                        .settimeout(90000)//time set for the connection 1 min
                        .execute();
                Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();

                Document doc = Jsoup
                    .connect("http:/some-site.com/home.jsp")
                    .cookies(cookies)
                    .get();
```

You can then work on **doc** object to get all the information you may need.

Comment: Gonna try this. Thank you.

Comment: Best of luck and please cast a vote or accept the answer if it helps :)